# how to solve Recurtion equation

Tags: complexity-theory, recursion

Does someone know how to solve the below?

$$T(n)=2T(n-1)-T(n-2)+5n+7$$

$$T(n)=2T(sqrt(n))+(logn/(log(logn))$$

$$T(n)=T(sqrt(n)[5])+log(log[3]n)$$

Comment: In the third expression, what are $[3]$ and $[5]$?

Comment: order of 3 and 5 of the function.